# PS Security - sql to obtain a list of navigation

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine, peoplesoft-query

Is it possible with SQL Server to get a list of navigation for a given role?

1. Get all the permissions listed under that role
2. For each of the permissions, get the pages
3. For each of pages/menu name get the list of authorized components
4. For each of the list of components, get the PS Navigation

tried it with qry manager and it din't work

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible to do with SQL but not in PSQUERY if you want a complete menu path

1. Get all the permissions listed under that role

Found in table: PSROLECLASS

2. For each of the permissions, get the pages

Found in table: PSAUTHITEM

3. For each of pages/menu name get the list of authorized components

Found in table: PSMENUITEM

4. For each of the list of components, get the PS Navigation

The content references are found in PSPRSMDEFN.

Fields to join on:

PORTAL_URI_SEG1 = MenuName

PORTAL_URI_SEG2 = Component

If you want the complete navigation path (eg: Root-> PeopleTools-> Security-> Permissions and Roles-> Permission Lists), that's a more complicated query. I ended up using a CTE which contained a recursive query on PSPRSMDEFN. Once I had that I joined the CTE to the above tables and was able to create something similar to what you want. I suggest adding the option (MAXRECURSION 20); hint to your recursive query to ensure you don't run into trouble while developing this